# How to find Incremental Updated records count for Migrating a last voume Data in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to migrate data incrementally in Oracle DB. Is there any PLSQL utility or script to find the incremental (updated) records each time?

Assume 100_000_000 records in database in initial Load then after couple of weeks received another set of records (approximately 1_000_000 records are updated). I need to incrementally identify the changed records and migrate to taget DB.

Comment: This question is poorly described. 1) How will you know a record is updated? a) update id, c) update date column
This is crucial to construct an answer. If nothing indicates that a row has been updated then this is (almost) impossible and only new rows can be inserted easily. (per column comparison for 100.000.000 rows is  not a smart thing to do)

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the new set of records into a staging table. Then use `MERGE INTO` to update the main table.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a timestamp column in the source data which reliably reflects insert/update time, then you just want everything later than your last successful extract (unless you need to handle source deletes, which will take some more work). If not, you'll probably have to look at [Oracle Goldengate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html).